# Vertically center-align a figcaption on an image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to align a `figcaption` over an image, in a centered way: 
[image: result desired]

So far, I have the following code:

```
.portfolio-item figcaption{
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    left: -20px;
    width: 280px;
    background: rgb(52,152,219);
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
}
```

For the following HTML:

```
<!-- PORTFOLIO IMAGE 1 -->

<div class="portfolio-item">
    <figure>
        <img  src="assets/img/portfolio/folio01.jpg" alt="">
        <figcaption>
                <h5>UI DESIGN</h5>
                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" >Take a Look</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

The problem is, to center it, I'm using `left: -20px;` which is definitely not that responsive. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Use percentage instead of px

Comment: Your code is not enough but try to use `margin: 0 auto` and get rid of the `left` property. Also, your padding can be simplified like this: `padding: 10px 5px` no need to repeat same value twice.

Comment: Thanks for the padding tip. However the margin isn't workink :(

Comment: I posted another answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, the flexbox one is perfect for as I'm more confortable with it, and it works like a charm! Actually, I had to use order: 1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox can do this. You don't need to use relative (or absolute) positioning.

- Make the entire `figure` element a flex container with `column`-direction.
- Center both image and caption with `align-items: center`.
- Switch the order of the image and caption with the flex `order` property.

```css
figure {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}

.portfolio-item figcaption {
 
 order: -1;             /* default value for all flex items is 1 */
 
 display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
 
        width: 280px;
        background: rgb(52, 152, 219);
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
 
 /* REMOVED
 position: relative;
        top: -40px;
        left: -20px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-item">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="100" height="100" alt="">
        <figcaption>
            <h5>UI DESIGN</h5>
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Take a Look</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try it out, but the top -40 is because it overlaps the image.

Comment: So I needed to remove the top property to make it work (yes it works!) However, I need the caption to overlay of 40px on the picture... Any idea?
Thanks a lot! EDIT: found my way around: bottom 40px works ;)

Answer (score 2):

```css
figure {
 position: relative;
 height: 400px;
 border: 1px dashed red;
}

figure > img {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;                     /* horizontal alignment */
 transform: translateX(-50%);   /* horizontal alignment (fine tuning) */
 z-index: -1;                   /* keep image under figcaption always */
}

figure > figcaption {
 position: absolute;
 top: 40%;                      /* vertical alignment */
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 
 display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
 
        width: 280px;
        background: rgb(52, 152, 219);
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-item">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="200" height="200" alt="">
        <figcaption>
            <h5>UI DESIGN</h5>
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Take a Look</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```